# Is it possible to access a JAX-WS from a web browser?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client

I was just wondering, whether is it possible to deploy a JAX-WS and access it from a browser without the need to install any software or proxy classes ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, JAX-WS is just a library built on top of SOAP, which is built on top of XML, which is built on top of HTTP (duh!)

If you have SOAP web services (the fact that it was developed using JAX-WS is irrelevant), any application capable of sending and receiving XML over HTTP can call it. We are successfully accessing our back-end web services using AJAX POST (the web services must be deployed on the same domain as your front-end due to [same-origin-policy](/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy)).

Comment: If you are talking about calling from typing an address in the address bar of a browser, its not possible because you need to send a SOAP request. But you can write simple form to submit. Else try SOAPUI or REST Client. You can build a SOAP request and POST.

Comment: Since when is XML build on top of HTML? Isn't it the other way around...Duh?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen it's not possible, since you need to have proxy classes in order to call the JAX-WS functions ... but maybe I'm wrong !

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: Proxy classes are only a means to build the SOAP request and post to the endpoint. IF you can build your SOAP request and invoke the end point with the request by any other means of posting to an http url, you dont need the proxy.